# How do i use java boolean condition in camel route?

Tags: java, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I am using camel to transfer files from one endpoint to another. I am starting multiple routes in which some routes need to decrypt the files. How can i make the unmarshal process optional in a specific route based on a boolean condition?

```
from(source)
    .choice()
    .when(isEncrypted())) //Java boolean value 
    .unmarshal(decrypt(pgpEncryptionDetails)) 
    .endChoice()
to(destination);

PGPDataFormat decrypt(PGPEncryptionDetails pgpEncryptionDetails) {
    PGPDataFormat pgpDataFormat = new PGPDataFormat();
    pgpDataFormat.setKeyFileName(pgpEncryptionDetails.getPrivateKeyPath());
    pgpDataFormat.setPassword(pgpEncryptionDetails.getPassphrase());
    pgpDataFormat.setKeyUserid(pgpEncryptionDetails.getUserId());
    return pgpDataFormat;
}
```

I know how to do with a simple expression but here my condition not depends on exchange.

Comment: Why can't you do this check if decryption is needed inside `decrypt()` itself?

Comment: @SubOptimal, I need to handle that before calling `unmarshal`. I have to skip `unmarshal()` itself, not just `decrypt()`. I have updated the code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working for me.

```
from(source)
    .process(exchange -> decryptIfEncrypted(pgpEncryptionDetails))
to(destination);

ProcessDefinition decryptIfEncrypted(PGPEncryptionDetails pgpEncryptionDetails) {
    if (isPgpEncryped()) {
        PGPDataFormat pgpDataFormat = new PGPDataFormat();
        pgpDataFormat.setKeyFileName(pgpEncryptionDetails.getPrivateKeyPath());
        pgpDataFormat.setPassword(pgpEncryptionDetails.getPassphrase());
        pgpDataFormat.setKeyUserid(pgpEncryptionDetails.getUserId());
        return new ProcessDefinition().unmarshal(pgpDataFormat);
    }
    return new ProcessDefinition();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method call expression to call a method on a java bean which implements the predicate

```
public class Foo {
  public boolean isSomething(Object body) {
    ... return true or false
  }
}
```

And then use the method in the Camel route

```
when(method(Foo.class, "isSomething"))
```