# Boolean condition in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Is there a way to do smth like this to work? I am talking about the condition inside when.

```
.choice()
       .when(Exchange::isFailed)
         .to(direct(URI_DEADLETTER))
```

I tried:

```
.when(method(Exchange.class, "isFailed"))
.when().exchange(Exchange::isFailed)
```

For the first solution an error is thrown and the second is not working. 
I know that I can create a new class and a method inside, from here: [How do i use java boolean condition in camel route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035368/how-do-i-use-java-boolean-condition-in-camel-route)
And I read about the predicat here: http://www.davsclaus.com/2009/02/apache-camel-and-using-compound.html.
But without using a new class or predicat, is there a way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

A lazy solution is to use **Camel simple language** (http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) which allows you to access anything (headers, properties, body, method, etc..) of current exchange

```
.choice()
.when( simple("${exception} != null") )
```

A more OO solution would be to use **Camel Predicate** (Builder):

```
Predicate condition1 = ...
Predicate condition2 = ...; 
Predicate isFailed = PredicateBuilder.or(condition1, condition2);   


.choice()
    .when( isFailed )
```